# How do you skip duplicate lines in the txt s?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

I'm capturing data from a website page, after that, I do name filtering to be stored simultaneously as input in a txt by the command:

```
   with open( 'Peoples.txt' , 'w' ) as archive :
       archive.write( x )
       archive.write('\n')
       archive.close()
```

The input data is being written simultaneously from the variable "X". As the data arrives, they will be repeated, staying that way.

```
  Isabela Novark
  Isabela Novark
  Isabela Novark
  Julian Ferrer
  Angelic Bertford
```

In short: How do I continue to receive data on txt without these repetitions?

Comment: If you use pandas dataframes, you can use the drop duplicates function.

Comment: You don't need to use `archive.close()` because the `with open()` statement automatically takes care of it.

Comment: @gnodab I don't know this tool yet

Comment: [Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) is the documentation for you to read up on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use pure Python solution, you can use set for storing already seen names.

For example:

```
names = ['Isabela Novark',
  'Isabela Novark',
  'Isabela Novark',
  'Julian Ferrer',
  'Angelic Bertford']

seen = set()

with open('Peoples.txt', 'w') as archive:
    for x in names:
        if x in seen:
            continue
        seen.add(x)
        print(x, file=archive)
```

Will create `Peoples.txt` with contents:

```
Isabela Novark
Julian Ferrer
Angelic Bertford
```